# Verifiy Database option is not working with crystal report in visual studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I am working in WPF project in visual studio 2022 with crystal report SP33. I have designed a crystal report in visual studio including 3 different class objects says Customer, CustomerOrders, CustomerProducts. It's working fine. But now I added one more field to the Customer class. When I right click on Database Fields in side-pane of report designer and click on Verify Database, it opens a dialog window, asking Please enter connection information like File path and Class name. Do anyone has idea how to get new fields in class in crystal report?
Please note that Verify Database is working fine on other reports having single classs as database. The problem is occur on reports having more than one classes as database.

Comment: 1) you have added a new field in "customer".kindly make sure you have updated the class definition in your project accordingly.

Comment: 2) Update the report : Open Crystal report and in Database expert ,you will see your existing class listed. right click on the class you have modified and select set datasource location